# Are there any concrete examples when using the Any type is a good solution?

Tags: swift, types, casting

We all know that swift has a strong type system, and as such I lean towards using this system to my advantage :)

Here's what Apple has to say about using the Any type:

> **Type Casting for Any and AnyObject**
>
> Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific
>   types:
>
> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. Any can
>   represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.
>   NOTE
>
> Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and
>   capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about
>   the types you expect to work with in your code.

I don't know if it's me, but I kind of think the code starts to smell when using these (This maybe my lack of experience using them) - I know AnyObject is required/useful for interacting with Objective-C so I get that there is a practical nature to AnyObject's use.

So I wanted to know what concrete examples represent a good use of the Any type.

For example is it could be used to pass unknown content to a POST request constructor method where the method could safely use optional chaining to examine the unknown content.

Apple's example from the [Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)](http://swift%20programming%20guide%20for%20beginners)

> **Any**
>
> Here’s an example of using Any to work with a mix of different types,
>   including function types and non-class types. The example creates an
>   array called things, which can store values of type Any:

```
var things = [Any]()

things.append(0)
things.append(0.0)
things.append(42)
things.append(3.14159)
things.append("hello")
things.append((3.0, 5.0))
things.append(Movie(name: "Ghostbusters", director: "Ivan Reitman"))
things.append({ (name: String) -> String in "Hello, \(name)" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When should I use `[Any]`?

`Any` is an abstract type that all other types implicitly conform to. Because it could be *anything* – it must be guaranteed to do *nothing*.

For that very reason, typing a variable as `Any` is nonsensical. If I define this:

```
let itCouldBeAnything : Any = "Actually it's a string"
```

It now can't do anything (without type casting):

[image]

You should always use the most descriptive type available when defining something, and because of `Any`'s abstract nature, there will *always* be a more descriptive type available – in this case, `String` should've been used.

Now let’s think about arrays. As you say, Apple demonstrates that you can use an array of `Any` to mix together different types.

```
var things = [Any]()

things.append(0)
things.append(0.0)
things.append(42)
things.append(3.14159)
things.append("hello")
things.append(Movie(name: "Ghostbusters", director: "Ivan Reitman"))
```

Great. But what does this array actually *represent*? It’s just a collection of junk – the programming equivalent of the backseat of my car.

If we try and do something with one of the elements...

[image]

We can’t. It could be *anything* – so we can’t do anything with it. Sure, we can type cast the elements with a `switch` or `if` statement to handle the different possibilities – but all we’ll succeed in doing there is splitting our array back into distinct types. So what was the point in using `[Any]` to begin with?

An array should always represent a collection of *related* data. There’s no point of an array if the elements share nothing in common. If the different types that the array can store have common functionality, then you should define a protocol with this common functionality:

```
protocol ACommonProtocol {
    // define common functionality
}
```

We can then conform the types that the array can store to it:

```
extension Int : ACommonProtocol {}
extension Double : ACommonProtocol {}
extension String : ACommonProtocol {}
extension Movie : ACommonProtocol {}
```

Now our array can be of type `[ACommonProtocol]`. This is a *significant* improvement from `Any`, we’ve narrowed the concrete types that the elements could be down to 4 – and we can now use any common functionality that we define in the protocol on the elements without type-casting. Our elements also are now *explicitly* related, which actually gives the array some meaning (assuming the protocol represents a meaningful concept).

If the different types that the array can store *don't* have any common functionality, or cannot conform to protocols (such as tuples and functions), but are still related in some meaningful way – then another way of expressing this relationship is through using an `enum` with associated values:

```
// obviously this enum (and possibly its cases) should have a far better names
enum IntDoubleStringOrMovie { 
    case int(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case string(String)
    case movie(Movie)
}
```

Now our array can be of type `[IntDoubleStringOrMovie]` – which has the added benefit of allowing us to use an exhaustive `switch` in order to determine the element type:

```
for element in array {
    switch element {
    case let .int(int):
        print(int)
    case let .double(double):
        print(double)
    case let .string(string):
        print(string)
    case let .movie(movie):
        print(movie)
    }
}
```

So for this reason, you should never ever have to use `[Any]` in Swift. If you ever find yourself in a situation of using `[Any]`, you should be re-considering your data structure. Whether that involves splitting the array up into sub-arrays, conforming the elements to a common protocol (if they have common functionality), using an enum with associated values (if they have no common functionality) or using a different collection type altogether, is entirely up to you.

#### But what about interfacing with Objective-C?

`Any` is sometimes necessary for bridging with Objective-C’s inferior type system – and therefore you may well find yourself using `[Any]` with Objective-C APIs, which is acceptable (although with [the bridging of Objective-C's lightweight generics](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0057-importing-objc-generics.md) to Swift, it should be uncommon).

The only thing I would say about this is once you’re back in your Swift logic, you should *always* convert an `[Any]` back to a meaningful array type through type casting, or unpacking it into a more appropriate data structure. You shouldn’t sacrifice type safety in Swift just because Objective-C lacks in that regard.

#### But what about `[AnyObject]`?

`AnyObject` is pretty much as vague as `Any` in pure Swift. The only thing it guarantees is that it’s a class. However, as of Swift 3, [*anything* can be bridged to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6) by being boxed in a `_SwiftValue`. For this reason, `[AnyObject]` is just as (if not *more*) questionable as `[Any]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pure Swift (without the legacy Objective-C stuff) and you want an array where you can put `Int`(s), `Bool`(s) and `String`(s) then you need an array of `Any`.

```
let values: [Any] = [1, true, "I'm not a pointer!"]
```

[image]

### But, wait I can also use an array of AnyObject right?

Nope. Infact `Int`, `Bool` and `String` in Swift are `struct`(s).

### They why does this code compile?

[image]

The code above compile because the `import Foundation` does enable the bridge to Objective-C. This mean the Swift `Int`, `Bool` and `String` are allowed to be seen as objects by the compiler in order to preserve compatibility  with Objective-C.

But as soon as you remove the `import Foundation` the code stop compiling.

[image]