# Error: Argument type double/string etc. does not conform to expected type "AnyObject"

Tags: swift

I watched some iOS programming tutorial and have a question on "AnyObject".
The bridging does not work.
I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain
{
    private var accumulator = 0.0
    var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()

    func setOperand (operand: Double) {
        accumulator = operand
        internalProgram.append(operand)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Same for string...

```
func performOperation (symbol: String) {
    internalProgram.append(symbol)
}
```

I know about `NSString` and the reference type vs. struct thing, and that double and string are no reference types.
But anyway in the tutorial the bridging worked fine...
What could be the reason for my failure?

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly say, `Double` and `String` are not reference types in Swift – they are `struct`s. Therefore you cannot directly store them in an `[AnyObject]`, you would first need to bridge them to Objective-C in order to do so.

Although bridging to Objective-C in this case is unnecessary – if you want an array of heterogenous types, including value types, then you can use an `[Any]`:

```
var internalProgram = [Any]()
```

However, from what I can tell, you *don't* want a array of *anything* ([it's very rarely a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299843/are-there-any-concrete-examples-when-using-the-any-type-is-a-good-solution)) – you just want an array that can contain a `Double` *or* a `String`.

You can describe this with an `enum`:

```
enum OperationArgument { // feel free to give me a better name
    case operand(Double)
    case symbol(String)
}
```

And now you can define an array of it:

```
var internalProgram = [OperationArgument]()

func setOperand (operand: Double) {
    internalProgram.append(.operand(operand))
}

func performOperation (symbol: String) {
    internalProgram.append(.symbol(symbol))
}
```

Now instead of conditional type-casting to get back the type of each element, you can just use a `switch` or an `if case`:

```
for element in internalProgram {
    switch element {
    case let .operand(operand):
        print(operand)
    case let .symbol(symbol):
        print(symbol)
    }

    if case let .operand(operand) = element {
        print(operand)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a Swift **value type** as an `AnyObject`, in Swift 3 you need to explicitly cast it to the old Objective-C object type.

So this

```
internalProgram.append(operand)
```

becomes this

```
internalProgram.append(operand as NSNumber)
```

And this

```
internalProgram.append(symbol)
```

becomes this

```
internalProgram.append(symbol as NSString)
```

> The tutorial you are talking about has probably been written with Swift 2 where you just needed to `import Foundation`.

Comment: cast to AnyObject should be enough, import Foundation is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()

func setOperand (operand: Double) {
    // you have cast operand as AnyObject !!
    internalProgram.append(operand as AnyObject)
}

setOperand(operand: 10)
print(internalProgram, type(of: internalProgram)) // [10] Array<AnyObject>
```