# How can this [AnyObject] return as AnyObject?

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, anyobject

```
import Cocoa

class Brain{
    var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()
    var program:AnyObject{
        get{
            return (internalProgram as AnyObject)
        }
    }
}

var savedProgram: AnyObject?
let brain = Brain()
func save(){
    savedProgram = brain.program
}
```

How can this `internalProgram:[AnyObject]` return as `AnyObject` without Xcode giving a warning or an error? I know that `program`'s type is set as `AnyObject` already but I mean how can this work and wasn't it supposed to be `[AnyObject]`? So why no any warning or error issue?

Comment: AnyObject can contain any object, including an array of AnyObject  [AnyObject]

Comment: return (internalProgram as! AnyObject)

Comment: @LeoDabus More specifically, it can contain an `NSArray`. A Swift array is not an `AnyObject`. I always prefer to write `as NSArray` or `as NSString` instead of `as AnyObject`.

Comment: That's the curse not to care for the type. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why no any warning or error issue?

There would have been if you hadn't of said `as AnyObject`:

```
class Brain {
    var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()
    var program: AnyObject {
        get {
            // compiler error:
            // Return expression of type '[AnyObject]' does not conform to 'AnyObject'
            return internalProgram
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is telling us that `[AnyObject]` doesn't conform to `AnyObject` – which is perfectly true. A Swift `Array` is a `struct`, not a `class`, therefore cannot directly be typed as an `AnyObject`.

However, you then say `as AnyObject`. By doing so, you're *bridging* the Swift `Array` to `NSArray` (when Foundation is imported) – which *is* a `class`. Therefore it can be typed as an `AnyObject`. You can see the full list of Foundation types which can be bridged to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61).

Furthermore it's worth noting that in Swift 3, [*everything* can be bridged to `AnyObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6) due to the introduction of the opaque `_SwiftValue` type, which can wrap an arbitrary Swift value in an Obj-C compatible box (including `Array` when Foundation isn't imported).

Because *anything* can now be an `AnyObject`, it's pretty much as weak a type as `Any`. On top of this, it also lets you call *any* known `@objc` method on it, completely disregarding type safety and is almost guaranteed to cause you problems with `_SwiftValue` boxing. For those reasons, you should avoid using `AnyObject` wherever you can. There [is nearly always a stronger type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37299843/2976878) available for you to use.

Comment: Thanx!!! Your explanation and tips are so great for me(a new guy learning Swift)! Have a nice day 

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow @QasaiNto :) If you feel your question has been answered, you can [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

According to *Apple's* documentation, **[`AnyObject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyobject)** can be used when:

> - you need the flexibility of an untyped object
> - you use bridged Objective-C methods and properties that return an untyped result

It basically can be used as a type for any instance of any class, no matter what that is. Therefore, `[AnyObject]`, converted to `NSArray`, is still an object, which `AnyObject` can hold, because its type does not matter, since `AnyObject` can hold any class type, such as `NSArray`.

---

#### Explanation:

`[AnyObject]` is an array of Objects, so it's a value type. However, when `Foundation` is imported, the array can automatically be converted to the Objective-C  bridged type `NSArray` which is *AnyObject*.

Comment: Suggestions are welcome and if you need clarifications about the answer, please let me know!

Comment: `[AnyObject]` is a value type therefore it *is not* an `AnyObject`, which represents only class types. However, when `Foundation` is imported, a Swift array can be bridged to `NSArray` which is an `AnyObject`. That's the important part here.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer with the information You've provided @Sulthan. Good to know!